# VBA browse all page from worksheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to work directly on `Pages` using VBA (Like if each page is a kind of worksheet)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you know the sheet names:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
ws.Cells(1,1).value = 1
```

Now you can manipulate every cell as needed

to iterate over all sheets:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, val as integer
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Debug.Print ws.Name
val = ws.cells(1,1)
Next
```

Comment: I mean, I want to iterate over each pages in worksheet...